# spark sql column contains control characters \n\r

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm reading from a hive table stored in ORC format with spark.sql and I'm expecting the text to contain control characters, like in this example:

```scala
            val dfx = Seq(
                  ("some text"),
                  ("some other \n text"),
                  ("some other \\n text")
                ).toDF("text")
        
        dfx.withColumn("transformed", regexp_replace(col("text"), "\n", "")).show(false)
    
    +------------------+------------------+
    |text              |transformed text  |
    +------------------+------------------+
    |some text         |some text         |
    |some other 
     text              |some other  text  |
    |some other \n text|some other \n text|
    +------------------+------------------+
```

What I am not expecting is for the control characters to appear as if they are escaped, or literals, like in the third row in the dataframe. And I don't recall seeing this before. Is there anything I am missing?

Thank you!

Comment: I believe that in the third row the first backslash escapes the second backslash, so the original text does not contain the control character `\n` (0x0A) but a single backslash plus a `n` (0x5C + 0x6E)

Comment: @werner yeah, the thing is that the original data should not contain a double backslash, just a simple newline character. I'm wondering if there's some setting, or property of the actual file that's treating everything as literals